# Tableau and MariaDB connectivity issues

Tags: sql, mariadb, tableau-api

I am trying to connect Tableau Desktop (tried version 9.2 and 2018.1 both) with MariaDB (Server version: 10.0.20-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server). I am selecting MySQL in the list of data source servers in Tableau. The connection is getting established but

```
1. Databases are not visible  
2. Custom SQL is not available Data refresh  
3. Live or extract options are not visible
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all the posts mention that connecting to MySQL data source works perfectly fine if we need to connect to MariaDB. There are, however, few differences.

Follow these steps in case of similar problem:
In connecting to the data source, select `Other Databases (ODBC)`
Select `Driver` and choose `MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver`
Provide connection details like server IP, port, username and password that is used to connect with MariaDB

That's it.